# How can I integrate DHL webservices

Tags: magento-1.9, shipping-methods, web-services, dhl

How can I integrate DHL web services. I need to integrate DHL for my shipping Rates.

[image]

Comment: you can use third party extension for integration . DHL doesn't provide Magento extension .. or you can create extension and use API provided by DHL

Comment: yes, how can i use DHL WSL

Comment: check this third party... https://shiptheory.com/integrate/magento/dhl

Comment: Your last suggestion really very nice, how can i connect DHL by using Web services(wsl)

Comment: you must have DHL developer account  . you need Gateway URL , Access ID,Password,Account Number

Comment: there must be any manager account of DHL.  use that for credentials or ask DHL about it.   http://www.dhl.co.in/en/express/resource_center/integrated_shipping_solutions/integrating_xml_services.html

Comment: okay, let me check...

Answer (score 0):

There is Free extension avliable please install this extension for your purpose

https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/dhl-auspost-startrack-fastway-couriers-please-shipping-extension.html

this extension provides you `DHL ,AusPost ,StarTrack, Fastway Couriers` integration please check this if its fit to your requirement install and check

Comment: DHL represent told, default magento DHL is not for all countries, its only for us, You have to use web services,  what can i do ??

Comment: Kindly help me to solve DHL updates not save error, https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/220467/57334